# How to recover files stored in a virtual machine running linux in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, vmware-workstation, xubuntu, file-recovery

I was running XUBUNTU in VMware workstation 10. Once when I was updating the virtual machine, it got stuck. I killed the process and after that when I was going to power on it again, it doesn't boot. It doesn't even comes to the logon screen. Are there any method to recover the files I stored in that machine ?

Comment: Assuming the VMDK filesystem is not encrypted and you're trying to do this on Windows 7 (since you tagged the post with that), a quick Google for "windows mount VMDK" shows a number of different things to try to get it mounted. Once done, you can use Ext2Fsd or EXT2IFS to read the filesystem on the mounted disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount a Linux Live CD ISO in the virtual machine's optical drive and boot it. It should be able to access files on those partitions and transfer them over a network or to a USB HDD.